# How to get sections next to each other in right place

Tags: html, css

I know this is probably easy to solve, but I just can't get it right. How do I get the blue section to just be the image (so not a blue block on its right) and then the red one next to the blue one? (same goes for green and yellow but they're fine for now).

```css
#div1 {
 float: left;
 background: blue;
 margin-top: 100px;
}

#div2 {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
 margin-top: 100px;
}

.div-container {
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#div3 {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 background: yellow;
 height: 100px;
}

#div4 {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="div-container">
  <div id="div1"><img src="img/Kenya elephants.jpg" alt="TravelPic" width="50%" height="50%"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="div-container">
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <div id="div4"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

[Example of what it looks like on a "phone" screensize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEgWM.png)

Comment: give the `div` the same `width` and `height` as the pic

Comment: why not use `background-image` to replace the `img` tag?

Comment: @YongQuan I tried doing that but then the blue section seems to just disappear and the red one goes over it

Comment: what is the expected outcome for the blue section? Is the picture supposed to cover the section or you need the blue background visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution(s) :-**

```
<style>
#div1 {
    float: left;
    background: blue;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height : 100px;
    width : 20% ;
}
#div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#div3 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px;
margin-top : 100px;
}
#div4 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top : 100px ;
    background: green;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="div-container">
        <div id="div1"><img src="img/Kenya elephants.jpg" alt="TravelPic" width="100%" height="100%"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-container">
        <div id="div3"></div>
        <div id="div4"></div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

**Explanation(s) :-**

```
I Had Made Some Changes With Your Code , Maybe you can take a look at them
and if they don't fit you , you can try their equivalents....
According to what I understood >>
I created a code for you , basically its your own code with a few changes 
I didn't exactly get what you wanted but , this is what I think you
want....
```

**Notes And References :-**

```
NOTE :: I changed some of the sizes (like the image tag)
and moreover I changed a few CSS style lines from your code and added my own
Hope it is what you are wanting...
```